# I can't get a startService working from my BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start my Service when an alarm gets triggered from my BroadcastReceiver. I am not getting any error and the code runs, but its not starting my service and I am not getting any errors. Could it be a problem that is in my Service or in the manifest?

I have noticed that I am often getting problems when it comes to Intents and Contexts. I have tried to read up on it, but I can't find a site that explains it in a good way though. Any suggestions?

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);

        Intent myService = new Intent(BackgroundService.class.getName());
        context.startService(myService); 
    }
}
```

********************** Manifest*******

```
<service android:name=".BackgroundService" android:process=":remote">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp.BackgroundService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent myService = new Intent(BackgroundService.class.getName());
```

This creates a new intent with just an action. The action is the name of the BackgroundService class. This won't work when you are using `startService()`.

Rather use the intent constructor that gets a class and a context as arguments instead:

```
Intent myService = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
```

Comment: I get same result. Looks good in Eclipse, but when I run the code in Android emulator the service never starts and no errors are given :(

Comment: @DavidSebela Are you sure that your broadcast receiver is registered properly and receives the appropriate broadcast? Try to add a breakpoint or log statement inside `onReceive()` and see if you end up there or if it doesn't get called. Also do the same inside your services onStart/onStartCommand.

Comment: I know that the alarm gets triggered, and that the onReceive runs. I have Log.d(); inside but I have removed them when posting. My Service is also doing alot and I know its not starting. But I have loads of stuff in my Service like timertasks and other stuff. So I will make a new Service to test things out more. Thanks loads :)

Comment: Hm ok. I guess the service is also registered properly in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

Got it :-D sort of. Now I know the problem. The code you suggested works.

```
Intent myService = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
context.startService(myService);
```

But the problem is that my Service is already running. I thought that it was killed, but only the timer was stopped and the service was still running. So when the two lines above are executed it basically dose nothing.

Now I have to find out how to really kill it :)

Comment: And using stopSelf(); made everything work like I wanted. Thanks loads alextsc