# ImageView move refreshes?

Tags: android

I've make a method which moved my `ImageView` via my touch points , But I wanna see the refreshes like Motion tween in Adobe flash if it possible , here is my code :

```
int x=0;
int y=0;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  super.onTouchEvent(event);
  int ActionEvent = event.getAction();
  switch (ActionEvent){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
      x = (int) event.getX();
      y = (int) event.getY();
    }
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{    
      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams ActionMove = new 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(FstBall.getLayoutParams());
      ActionMove.x = x;
      ActionMove.y = y;
      FstBall.setLayoutParams(ActionMove);
    } 
    break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. I'm not even trying to read it this way and leave this question alone instead. Others who can answer will probably do the same.

Comment: Sorry , What do you mean about indent?

Comment: I made some changes to the indentation to make it more readable. Please accept the edit.

Comment: It's actually pretty hard to find a suitable link for someone who doesn't know what that is. The next best thing I could find is [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style). Code indention means to put spaces/tabs in front of your statements to reflect the structure of the source.  E.g. look at the code snippet in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456856/i-cant-get-a-startservice-working-from-my-broadcastreceiver). The more  nested a statement is, the more spaces it has in front. E.g. it's very easy to see which statements belong to `onReceive()`

Comment: I approved Mikes edit, have to wait for a second approval. You will see what i mean in a second. :)

Comment: Aha , You're right but indent just a coding style , Might be helping to reader to better response but won't help the coder :-) Thanks Mike

Comment: Actually, it often helps the coder as well. Good indentation helps avoid stupid bugs involving, for example, unmatched parentheses. Also, as alextsc stated, if other users on StackOverflow find it too much trouble to read your code, they will likely ignore your question. Everyone benefits from good style.

Comment: Okay you're right , I would surrender :-D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not want to use AbsoluteLayout as it is deprecated. There are plenty of tutorials on Android Drag-and-Drop. [Here's one](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) I recall being useful. I believe it uses FrameLayout and adjusts the left and top margins. You'll also want to check the API Demos. I think I remember an example project there. What do you mean by Adobe motion tween?

Comment: First of all Thank you about your edit and that useful article , Now back to the point ,My codes are working But I wanna show refreshes. some guys told me use View.Invalidate(); but it doesn't work , If you work with Adobe Flash we have section which name is Motion tween for rotational motion , I just wanna made sth like that.

Comment: What do you mean by refreshes? When you press down on the imageview, and drag the view around, does the view follow with your finger? Or does it only refresh when you lift your finger? Also, I'm not sure why you need Flash. Android has nice libraries for [animating views.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html)

Comment: Only refresh when I lift my finger , I do not need Flash - I just make an example.

Comment: That's because in the Move case, you are only updating some variables x and y. In the up case is when you set those LayoutParams. As it is now, the Move case is doing practically nothing. A quick fix is to just copy and paste the Action_Up code into Action_Move. If it still doesn't update, appending a call to `invalidate();` should do the trick.

Comment: Do the following. Comment out Action_Move. Change Action_Up to Action_Move. Alter the line to `ActionMove.x = (int) event.getX();` Do the same for y. Add `invalidate();` after setLayoutParams(). If that doesn't work, I'd recommend switching to FrameLayout (since as I said earlier, AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and thus, its behavior can be a bit unpredictable) and following the instructions in the tutorial I gave you.